# Generating next billing date automatically when the date is entered

Tags: excel, vba

Friends,

I want to generate the next billing cycle in excel when the current date is entered in a perticular cell. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Hellooo... Can anybody help me?

Comment: We need more information. How is the next billing cycle defined / calculated and how do you want to solve this problem? A user defined function or a vba macro that runs through a range of cells? Tell us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first billing date is in cell `A1` then your next billing date is `=EDATE(A1,1)`, assuming you have monthly billing. Change the second argument to 3 for quarterly, 6 for semiannual, etc.

Hope this helps.